# Can I halt QGIS doing calculations while I work on the code?

Tags: qgis, aggregate

I have a project that quite heavily relies on aggregate() functions and I can live with that it takes QGIS a quarter to do all the calculations.

But QGIS wants to redo all the calculations nomatter what small edits I am performing and working with the project takes forever in waiting time.

Is there a way to tell QGIS not to do any calculations until I ask for it?

As a work around I have created a small pseudo data set to work on but it is quite tedious to have to close down and reopen just to do a minor change in a formula.

Comment: If it's just a matter of editing a formula in Field Calculator/Expression Builder and QGIS re-evaluates the expression every time you so much as type a comma, that's the intended operation. You could raise a feature request at the QGIS Github page. I sometimes do my edits in Notepad ++ and then paste them back into QGIS when I'm done fixing syntax errors and the like. Or break my expression up into chunks and comment out unnecessary sections when I just want to test one part without evaluating the rest

Comment: Another workaround can be to unzip the .qgz file and edit the formulas in the .qgs file (which is an xml file). But code like this "hurts my eyes": 

expression="aggregate( layer:='Data_Indsatsomr',&#xd;&#xa;aggregate:='sum',&#xd;&#xa;expression:=  &quot;BolGT58Hast&quot; &#xd;&#xa;)"